# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' when trying to fetch core data objects to TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

Trying to fetch core data object to tableview and got an exception of `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "seminar"; desired type = NSString; given type = UITextField;`

`TeacherViewController.m` save data, fetch & show it in tableview on `TeacherDataViewController.m` 
**

> TeacherViewController.h

**

```
- (IBAction)btnsubmit:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedobjectcontext];
    NSManagedObject *new = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Teacher" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [new setValue:self.txtseminar forKey:@"seminar"];
    [new setValue:self.txtassignment forKey:@"assignment"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"can't save!! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

**

> TeacherDataViewController.m

**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
             myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:([self.lblsemnr.text valueForKey:@"seminar"]), ([self.lblassmnt.text valueForKey:@"assignment"]), nil];
        }
        -(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
            return 1;
        }
        -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
        {
            return self.devices.count;
        }
        -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            static NSString *cellidentifier = @"cell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellidentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
            }
            cell.textLabel.text = [myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            return cell;
        }
```

Doesn't save any data and throws above mentioned exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in the below line you are setting txtSeminar to seminar. txtSeminar seems to be a TextField, you should use txtSeminar.text

```
[new setValue:self.txtseminar forKey:@"seminar"];
```

Comment: that worked for saving data, thank you :)  but it isn't passed to `TeacherDataViewController.m` & code crashes

Comment: Nice. Mark this post as answer, so we can close this. Post another question for the code crash issue.